# MacBook Pro screen border repair

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, repair

I had a little accident with my MacBook Pro (dropped it).  The screen is working fine (no problem with screen display so far), it did not break but the little bar like "border" that contains it, is the one who took the damage and looks like this:

[image]

Is it reparable? How much would it cost (considering the screen is working and did not break)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MacBook Pro display is an assembly of glass (includes the border) “glued” to the LCD panel.  This means that to repair the glass you either need to replace the assembly or have the ability to remove the glass panel and re-glue it with the specialized adhesive in an industrial oven.

In short, replacing the glass isn’t a DIY project, however if you have decent tech skills, you should be able to replace the LCD assembly.

The glass will continue to shatter and is quite dangerous.  It’s best that you get it replaced sooner rather than later.

Comment: Understand, how much could this cost?

Comment: Which model MBP (year, and size)?

Comment: 13-Inch, 2020, four Thunderbolt 3 ports

Comment: The display assy. is around $500 USD. Figure another $200 for labor